# Insert a dataframe between dataframes via the nested append method

Tags: python, pandas

The following code works fine to insert one dataframe underneath the other using a nesting of the append method.

```
for sheet_name, df in Input_Data.items():
    df1 = df[126:236]
    df=df1.sort_index(ascending=False)
    Indexer=df.columns.tolist()
    df = [(pd.concat([df[Indexer[0]],df[Indexer[num]]],axis=1)) for num in [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
    df = [(df[num].astype(str).agg(','.join, axis=1)) for num in [0,1,2,3,4,5]]
    df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df=df.loc[0].append(df.loc[1].append(df.loc[2].append(df.loc[3].append(df.loc[4].append(df.loc[5])))))
```

However I need to add additional dataframes(one row, one column) in between df.loc[i] and as a first step, I tried to insert a dataframe  at the top of df.loc[0] via

```
df=df_1st.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

Which yields the following error `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

It seems my dataframe df has duplicate indices. Not sure how to proceed. Perhaps the nested method is not best approach?